# Who am I? (visual puzzle)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, visual

If...

[image]

...then:

[image]

(post your answer as a picture)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I propose:

> [image]

Because

> Graham Hill + Colin Chapman = Graham Chapman

and

> Richard Feynman + **David Attenborough** = Richard Attenborough.