# Celebrity Four Square

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, visual

Which celebrity completes this four square?

[image: celebrity_four_square]

Thanks to Megaptera novaeangliae for inspiring this puzzle.  See here:
[Who am I? (visual puzzle)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111101/who-am-i-visual-puzzle)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The missing celebrity is:

> **[Michael Douglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Douglas)**
>
>  [image]

Because the other 3 are:

> Top left: [Buster Keaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buster_Keaton)
>  Top right: [Buster Douglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buster_Douglas)
>  Bottom left: [Michael Keaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Keaton)
>
>  i.e. Celebrities in the same column share a surname, while celebrities in the same row share a first name.