# The Fellowship of the Square

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, history, movies

**What brings these four fellows together?**

```
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                                |                              |
|                                |                              |
|     played Caligula            |     played Jack Kerouac      |
|     in 1976                    |     in 1980                  |
|                                |                              |
|                                |                              |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                                |                              |
|                                |                              |
|     played William Marshal     |     played a role in the     |
|     in 2010                    |     history of Louisiana     |
|                                |     1900-1904                |
|                                |                              |
|                                |                              |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: If you crave more of this type of puzzle, see here:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111113/celebrity-four-square

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square

> Is actually a table!
>
> It can be set up as the following:
>
>           `|       Hurt      |      Heard     |`
> `-----------------------------------------------`
>   `John    |    John Hurt    |   John Heard   |`
> `-----------------------------------------------`
>  `William  |   William Hurt  |  William Heard |`

Where the answers, in order are

> [John Hurt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074006/characters/nm0000457?ref_=tt_cl_t_2), [John Heard](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080854/), [William Hurt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0955308/characters/nm0000458) and [William Wright Heard](https://www.sos.la.gov/HistoricalResources/AboutLouisiana/LouisianaGovernors1877-Present/Pages/WilliamWrightHeard.aspx)